# Obtener el porcentaje de una cantidad sobre otra en PHP

Tags: php, porcentaje, numberformat

Estoy intentando hacer una función a la cual pasando una `$cantidad`, esta debe **devolver el porcentaje de dicha cantidad sobre el total**, `$total`.

```
function obtenerPorcentaje($cantidad) {
    $total = (float)$row['total']; // Obtener total de la base de datos
    $porcentaje = ((float)$cantidad * 100) / $total; // Regla de tres
    $porcentaje = round($porcentaje, 0);  // Quitar los decimales
    return $porcentaje;
}
```

El problema es que me devuelve siempre `0` o `INF`(infinito), pero si en vez de `(float)$row['total']` pongo por ejemplo: `5000.758294`, sí funciona.

Para que puedan ayudarme, les explicaré todo:

- `$row['total']` es un valor almacenado en una base de datos en un campo *FLOAT*, y haciendo el `var_dump` de esta variable obtengo: `string(11) "2938.483920"`, y usando el **(float)** antes de la variable obtengo: `float(2938.483920)`.
- `$cantidad` recibe el valor con el que se va a calcular el porcentaje y en este mismo caso es: `string(10) "374.839284"`, pero con el (float) se vuelve a `float(374.839284)`
- Las operaciones son una [regla de tres](https://cdnblog-199133.c.cdn77.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/formula-regla-de-3-img1.png), donde se multiplica el **$valor** por `100` y se divide entre la `$cantidad`.
- Estoy usando `round()` porque represento el **porcentaje** usando ProgressBar, al cual debo pasar un número entero.

Estoy seguro de que el problema viene del los **números**, que están obtenidos con un formato incorrecto o algo así, ya que como he mencionado, tan solo con cambiar `(float)$row['total']` a un número *ya funciona perfectamente*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si usas $row['total'] sin pasarlo por parámetro, deberia de ser declarado como global en otro lugar.
Lo más correcto seria que pases el total como parametro de tu función

```
function obtenerPorcentaje($cantidad, $total) {
    $porcentaje = ((float)$cantidad * 100) / $total; // Regla de tres
    $porcentaje = round($porcentaje, 0);  // Quitar los decimales
    return $porcentaje;
}
```

o que declares tus rows como global (definitivamente no recomendado)

```
function obtenerPorcentaje($cantidad) {
    global $rows;
    $total = (float)$row['total']; // Obtener total de la base de datos
    $porcentaje = ((float)$cantidad * 100) / $total; // Regla de tres
    $porcentaje = round($porcentaje, 0);  // Quitar los decimales
    return $porcentaje;
}
```

y que la función que llame esta, también tenga el $rows como global.

Eventualmente puedes también pasar los rows como parámetro

```
function obtenerPorcentaje($cantidad, $rows) {
```

Tu código deberia de haberte enviado un warning que no estaba definida la variable $rows por cierto... sigue las pistas del interpretador.